# Creating a variable to count number of zero values across variables occurring in each observation- R

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out a way to do this in R and for the life of me can't figure it out. Let's say I have a df consisting of the following.

```
v1<- c(0, 0, 2, 0 1 3)
v2<- c(1, 0, 8, 1 ,0)
v3<- c(0, 1, 3, 0, 0)
v4<- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
df<- data.frame(v1, v2,v3, v4)
```

I want to create a new variable, say num_zeros, that counts the number of 0s for each observation in v1 to v3. Is there a quick way to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowSums` on a logical `matrix` to get the count of 0 values and assign it to 'num_zeros' column

```
df$num_zeros <- rowSums(df[c('v1', 'v2', 'v3')] == 0)
```

---

Or another option is

```
df$num_zeros <- (df$v1 == 0) + (df$v2 == 0) + (df$v3 == 0)
```

NOTE: Both methods are efficient and are vectorized

Answer (score 0):

We can use `apply` rowwise :

```
cols <- paste0('v', 1:3)
df$num_zeros <- apply(df[cols] == 0, 1, sum)
```

Or with `lapply` :

```
df$num_zeros <- Reduce(`+`, lapply(df[cols], `==`, 0))
```